# React Router 1.0 IndexRoute and activeClassName

Tags: react-router

I have a list of users, and when I click one I want the users messages route to load automatically. Sounds like a job for IndexRoute!

```
  <Route path="users" component={Users}>
    <Route path=":id" component={User}>
      <IndexRoute component={Inbox} />
      <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox} />
      <Route path="profile" component={Profile} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
```

I when I load the user I also have a nested navigation, eg Inbox, Profile, Friends, etc. I was assuming that the `IndexRoute` would automatically add the `activeClassName` attribute when the index loads, but it does not.

The links are in the following format:

```
<Link to={`/admin/users/${this.state.user.id}/inbox`} activeClassName="active">Inbox</Link>
```

When I first load the user, the index component does indeed show, however the inbox link does not add the active class. When I click the link explicitly it correctly adds the active class.

What is the best way to show that the inbox link is active by default when loading a user?

Comment: I would like to know this answer too, do you have the solution for it now?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the  component, try pairing it with:

```
  <IndexLink to="..." activeClassName="active">Inbox</IndexLink>
```

in the UI.